# Facebook Graph API gives random profile picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, caching, cdn

When I call `https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/picture?width=180&height=180` it redirects to the users profile picture image. When I change the profile picture and then call the link again from chrome it redirects to the old profile picture. When I call the link from safari it redirects to the new profile picture. In chrome incognito mode it redirects to randomly between old and new profile picture. I thought of browser caching but that couldn't be the case for incognito mode. What exactly is the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Caching in another place, such as Facebook’s CDN.

Comment: @CBroe but why is chrome incognito shows randomly?

Comment: Because of network issue, request may hit different servers. So it turns out randomly.